# Publish Snappy Apps Programtically

Tags: package-management, application-development, ubuntu-core, click-packages

Is it possible to publish Ubuntu open source snappy apps programmatically?

I would love to be able to publish a new version of the app in my CI system, when I push a new tag.

Is this currently possible? I have only seen an option to publish snappy apps manually.

Or should I make this PPA thing? Can I put snappy apps on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no stable public API for uploading apps to the store, no. Soon, any uploaded packages will require the author to sign them with gpg as well. Automating signing of your packages in a CI, would mean you'd need a private key with no password, and getting that key into a CI system may mean needing to have it published in a public location, thus compromising the integrity of any signature.

Also, no, you cannot publish snap packages into PPAs. PPAs are for creating deb packages.

Comment: In most CI's you can have encrypted variables, even if they are open source.

Comment: Is there a roadmap/issue somewhere for the public api for uploading apps? Any sort of timeline on this?

Comment: We have unstable APIs available, but they are not guaranteed to be stable (as in, we break them with a certain frequency).
There's a convenient Python client provided as documentation and example here: https://launchpad.net/click-toolbelt/